# Why isn't the boundary restored after a fielder pushes it out?

Tags: cricket

Quite often, a fielder near the boundary dives to try to stop the ball, and in the process pushes the boundary rope further away. I have never seen the boundary rope being restored to its original position.

This will put the batting side at a disadvantage. If the batsman plays another shot to the same place, the ball has to cover longer distance. Nowadays, it is also a common sight for a fielder to take spectacular catches close to the boundary, so that little push to the boundary rope can make a drastic difference.

Nobody seems to care about this issue, even the commentators don't consider it worth mentioning. What is the reason for ignoring this issue?

Comment: As suggested by [ʀᴇᴅ_ᴅᴇᴠɪʟ226](http://sports.stackexchange.com/a/13168/540) the boundary is restored every time, I have seen many times some cricketers restore the rope after they displace it during their miss fielding before going back to their fielding position.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, the boundary is restored every time it has been displaced by a fielder (or any other agent). You never see it happening because the broadcasting companies never end up showing it. This is largely due to the fact that there is always something more interesting to show than the replacing of the boundary ropes. As you rightly mentioned, even a few centimetres seems to make quite a difference in cricket today, and hence the restoring of the boundary rope to its original position is very important.

Next time you go to a stadium to watch a cricket match, observe the boundary rope after it has been displaced (for whatever reason). You will notice someone (ball boy/ substitute player/ stadium official) will restore the boundary rope to its original position. (NOTE: This might cause you to miss out on some cricketing action happening around the pitch).

Comment: Thanks, this is good to know. It has been a few years since I went to a stadium to watch a cricket match, I may not have paid enough attention back then. :-)